# Replace Constants with actual values Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Hi I have a template store in db: as following:

```
<p>Dear [[OWNER_NAME]],</p>

<p><br />
We are thanks put&nbsp;[[LOCATION_NAME]] to you.</p>

<p>It is very early stagesyou know.</p>

<p>If anything comes of it, we will be in contact immediately with a further email.</p>

<p>Best wishes,</p>

<p>[[CUSTOMER]]</p>
```

So when I am sending the email with this template I want to replace the above constants with actual values:

Like `[[CUSTOMER]]` is "Jemes" etc. Because I have already stored the constants, is there any way to know which constants need to be replaced with which values before sending this email template to customer ?

I am using Symfony2.8 with mysql

```
//Controler code Is:
public function sendEmails(){

return $this->render('action_and_message/messageTemplates/emailTemplates /emailTemplate.html.twig', array(
            'error' =>"",
            'data' =>$getTemplates->getEmailTemplate()
        ));

}  
//My Twig is

{% extends 'emailTemplateLayout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}

    <div style="width:80%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px">
{{ data | raw}}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you might need to create and use database template loader, here's an example (its a bit ugly but it works):

```
class DBTwigLoader implements \Twig_LoaderInterface, \Twig_ExistsLoaderInterface
{
    protected $dbh;
    protected $table;

    public function __construct(\PDO $dbh, $table = 'tmpl_twig')
    {
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
        $this->table = $table;
    }

    public function getSource($name)
    {
        if (false === $source = $this->getValue('source', $name)) {
            throw new \Twig_Error_Loader(sprintf('Template "%s" does not exist.', $name));
        }
        return $source;
    }

    // Twig_ExistsLoaderInterface as of Twig 1.11
    public function exists($name)
    {
        return $name === $this->getValue('name', $name);
    }

    public function getCacheKey($name)
    {
        return $name;
    }

    public function isFresh($name, $time)
    {
        if (false === $lastModified = $this->getValue('last_modified', $name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $lastModified <= $time;
    }

    protected function getValue($column, $name)
    {
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT ' . $column . ' FROM '.$this->table.' WHERE name = :name');
        $sth->execute(array(':name' => (string)$name));
        return $sth->fetchColumn();
    }
}
```

After that you can render do this:

```
$loader = new DBTwigLoader($dbh);
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

//echo $twig->render('index.twig', array('name' => 'Fabien'));
//or eventually Im doing that (I use just some blocks):
$template = $twig->loadTemplate($messagesPayload['template_name']);
$bodyHtml = $template->renderBlock('bodyHtml', ['recipient' => $recipient]);
```

Template_name will be 'yourtempname' which will be under name column in db. Make sure you prepare schema, for a bit of more details have a look at that: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#using-a-database-to-store-templates

Sample template that works with code above:

```
{% block subject 'Welcome to newsletter, ' ~ data.name %}

{% block bodyHtml %}
    <div style="background-color: black; color: lime;">
        Here is <strong>free trial of our new soft</strong>.
        As of our experience <strong><i>we think that:</i></strong><br/> {{ data.message  }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

For the moment Im using a service that wraps twig and just this service render templates from database, but Im I think you can connect it to your base Twig service if you find it more convenient.

**Template from string**

I'm not sure why you're using constants in templates, but it'd be better to convert them to proper Twig templates i.e. [[OWNER_NAME]] to {{ OWNER_NAME }} and then Twig will take care of replacing values...

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //this will create twig template from string and array of data
        $template = $this->get('twig')->createTemplate(
                    "testing {{OWNER_NAME}} tests {{CUSTOMER}}"
        );
        $templateString = $template->render(
                    array('OWNER_NAME'=>'Joe', 'CUSTOMER' => 'some customer')
        );

        // if you're not using it yet, try out dump (VarDumper component), 
        //included in Symfony standard, it will show in webtoolbar as well
        dump($template);
        dump($templateString);

        //return response if in controller (*using symfony 3.2)
        return new Response($templateString);
    }
}
```

If you dont want to convert templates in database then you can use str_replace() function to replace [[ with {{ and ]] with }} just before passing to crateTemplate function.

If you decide to stick with [[VAR]] format then str_replace() or better by preg_replace_(all) can be answers for you, but I dont see point in doing that if you're using Symfony and twig.

Comment: Actualy , I am not storing complete template in db I am storing only the content part in a db column. is there any other way to just find replace these variables with values at run time while sending emails.